# how to move div right to left in jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, html

i want to move a div from right to left on page load,but i am unable to make it work.I checked other answers and copied them but still it isnt working .I think mainly because the div is nested inside other div ,i tried different combinations of the main div and the nested div's inside it ,still it isnt working

```
  <div class='wrapper16'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid_12 s6">
        <h2>RESEARCH & DEVELOPMENT</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid_6 mar_t_25 s7">


        <p class="p4 mar_t_15">
         Research and Development is continuosly carried out on the existing and future products to make these more price competitive without comprimisng the quality of the products.<br />
            Research & Development is a constant feature for maintaining high temperature stability polymers. </p>
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery is:

```
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';

    var duration = 500;

    $('#wrapper16').toggle(effect, "right", duration);
  }); 
< /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").css({"left":"500px"}).animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Hello! I am a div!
</div>
```